# Custom openid connect provider adb2c

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, openiddict, openid-provider

I have created a custom identity provider in adb2c for my openid connect server but getting error while running it through User Flow -

[image]

Setps I did :

1. Created a new openId Connectprovider.

[image]

2. Created a new user flow for open-id connect provider :

[image]

I am not sure how to debug this through adb2c as that's a quite generic error and if I am missing any steps.

Comment: Does external Identity provider in adb2c supports device code flow?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may cause if your client ID is incorrect in the web.config file for the app

- Try to Open  Web.config file for the app
- In  Web.config file,try to find the app key **ida:ClientId**.
- The client ID provided in the portal for your app should be used as the value of the app key.

The file's modified section looks like

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="**xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx**">
</appSettings>
```

Credits to [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-sign-into-app)